# How can I change the permissions on my time machine from read only to read and write?

Tags: time-machine, permission

Recently I have been trying to move over from my previous drive that I used for Time Machine to a newer one.  I was checking the permissions before the move and I noticed this.  I am able to access the files that I saved before but am unable to edit it due to the permissions being set to read only.  I've tried looking it up online to see if I could change the permissions to read and write with the get info but this one doesn't have the drop down or ability to change the permissions.    I have also been able to back it up so I know it's not the read only error.
I'm not sure if time machine was supposed to be set to ready only but if possible, can someone help me change it to read and write?

[image: This is what it shows up on my computer right now]

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) Have you researched how to transfer Time Machine data from one drive to another?

Comment: I have.  So from what I have seen, I need a backups.backupdb or a sparsebundle file extension to copy over to my new drive.  However, I cannot find either of those on my time machine drive.  From the tutorials I have seen, they all have a backups.backupdb folder of where all of their time machine backups are stored there.  Mine however just has time machine backups folder for each day I have backed up on it.  I have also tried searching for a sparsebundle file extension on the drive and have come up short.

Comment: I don't have  BIg Sur Mac with a directly attached Time Machine drive, so I'll have to let someone who does double-check that, but all the Time Machine drives of various sorts here all have either Backups.backupdb or [*mac name*].sparsebundle as the first itm inside the drive.